# Tag search on Stack Overflow is stuck in the 'Bounties' tab state

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Picking any tag, for example, 'c' then `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c` returns a result page with 0 results (and sidebar, header). This is the same for every tag I've tried.

Platfor: Firefox 3.0.11 on Mac OS X.

How I reproduced:

I did this:

1. I clicked on one of the tabs - Questions
2. I clicked on a tag  'svn' in the main list of questions
3. I got a 0 search result

The title of the final page says "Bounty 'svn' Questions" so some session state is clearly confused and all my tag searches are stuck onto questions with bounties only.

**Result:** not a bug, but it is confusing (see the accepted answer), but you have to click on the lower of the two set of tabs - active / featured / hot / .. in order to get unstuck.

Comment: can't reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably on the wrong tab. Check the tab.

Remember our tab selections are "sticky".

> so some session state is clearly confused and all my tag searches are stuck onto questions with bounties only.

edit: You selected that tab so it stays selected -- as I said. It's "sticky". So you are browsing bountied questions only *until you select another tab*.

Comment: ok, you are correct but I assumed you meant the Questions / Tags / .. tab! NOT the Hot / Featured / ... tab!   This was not clear and I've been using SO for months.